# нужен код JS, чтобы при прокрутке изменялся цвета div

Tags: javascript, css, прокрутка

Есть такой пример:

```css
.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  position: fixed;
}
.active {
  float: left;
  background-color: #54a58b;
  padding: 16px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000;
}
.neactive {
  float: left;
  padding: 16px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <div id="1" class="active">200px</div>
  <div id="2" class="neactive">400px</div>
  <div id="3" class="neactive">600px</div>
  <div id="4" class="neactive">800px</div>
</div>
content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>content
<br>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке на 400px, другой `div` стал `active`, при прокрутке 600 - другой стал `active` и т.д. ?

Comment: Это вы нам задание даете?) Думаю вам лучше конкретизировать проблему: указать, что вы уже пробовали сделать и что именно не получилось

Comment: @DmitriySimushev человек эвент скролла ищет. но по мнению закрывающих, "нельзя дать лаконичный ответ" о том, как обработать скролл.

Comment: @PashaPash, если бы человек искал эвент скролла, то в вопросе так и было бы написано. А сейчас это вопрос вида "_сделайте за меня_". И да, в текущем виде от он не конкретен.

Answer (score 1):

Обработайте событие скролла (например, через [jQuery .scroll(...)](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)). В обработчике проверьте смещение скролла и поменяйте класс у соответствующего div.